# Как включить поддержку CopyTo для архивации файлов?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, консоль

На YouTube нашел способ архивации файла: [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BH9-H-b41Ys)

Но VisualStudio 2015 выдает ошибку на `CopyTo`

Может необходим какой-то компонент?

Или не хватает определенного **using System**....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

static class Program
{
    static string filename = @"C:\test.txt";
    static string outputFilename = @"C:\test.gzip";

    static void Compress()
    {
        using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outputFilename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    inputStream.CopyTo(gzip);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Compress();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, такой метод у стрима [присутствует](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.Stream.CopyTo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) доступен начиная с .NET Framework 4.0, поэтому, рекомендую проверить версию фреймворка в настройках проекта. Если по каким-то причинам вы используете версию ниже, то рассмотрите вариант с [Read/Write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5730893/7612728)